# Self de-/registering Observer over multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, observers

I have a problem with correctly locking a notification center
with self-registering observers. Specifically I run into already destroyed objects within event dispatching.

Consider the following structure:

- A Notification center is broadcasting events to multiple observers
- Observers register/derigister themselves on on creation/deletion.

  - this can happen at any time
- Event dispatch may be on a different thread than observer registration.
- To synchronize Observer registration and dispatch, both functions are locked.

In the end it should be something like this minimal example:

```
#include <future>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <map>

class Event {};
class Observer;
class Center {
public:
  void addObserver(Observer &o);
  void removeObserver(Observer &o);

  void sendEvent(Event*);
  static Center& instance() {static Center center; return center;}
private:
  std::map<Observer*, std::function<void(Event*)>> m_observers;
  std::mutex m_mutex;
};
class Observer {
public:
  virtual void onEvent(Event*) = 0;
  void call(Event * event) {onEvent(event);}
  Observer() {Center::instance().addObserver(*this);}
  virtual ~Observer() {Center::instance().removeObserver(*this);}
};
void Center::addObserver(Observer &o) {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m_mutex);
  m_observers[&o] = std::bind(&Observer::call,&o,std::placeholders::_1);
}
void Center::removeObserver(Observer &o) {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m_mutex);
  m_observers.erase(&o);
}
void Center::sendEvent(Event* e) {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m_mutex);
  for(auto i : m_observers) 
    i.second(e);
}
class testObs : public Observer {
  virtual void onEvent(Event*) {std::cout << "do work" << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
  auto handle = std::async(std::launch::async, []() {
    Event e;
    while(true) {Center::instance().sendEvent(&e);}
  });
  for(;;){testObs t1,t2,t3,t4;}
  handle.get();
}
```

This will run into a runtime error (`R6025 -pure virtual function call`) after some time.
The problem is that `Observer::~Observer()` is called only after `testObs` was destroyed,
so the lock is too late and a running the event dispatch will call a destroyed object.

My question is if I can still create a reliable lock (or implement another way of removing the object cleanly) while
keeping most of the existing structure:

- Automatic Observer registration/deregistration
- No Observer-ownership within the notification center

Comment: I would highly suggest NOT rolling your own observer/notification library. I would highly suggest checking out [Boost::signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/signals2.html)

Comment: @Mgetz I'm using `Poco::NotificationCenter` in combination with `Poco::Observer`, `Poco::NotificationQueue`, etc. This problem arised while implementing my structure with those classes, I just created a simple example using plain c++, but the situation is the same. I will have a look at boost::signals2 however; maybe the design prevents problems like that.

Comment: First of all, make the Observer destructor virtual.

Comment: How much control do you have on the rest of the code? Can you use shared pointers for classes that derive from Observer?

Comment: @YochaiTimmer Subclasses of this will be used by other developers, which do not have experience with shared pointers. If there is no other way then I could live with it, but I would prefer it to work with RAII on local objects as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race between notification and constructor of Observer for the virtual method onEvent:

the testObs is not yet fully constructed (the virtual method initialized), but it is already registered in the Center by the Observer constructor.

To debug this try adding printing statements in your constructors.

To fix it: register your testObs in the constructor of testObs rather than Observer's constructor.

There is also the same problem with destructor: move the deregistration to destructor of testObs.

Alternatively provide an empty implementation of onEvent:

```
virtual void onEvent(Event*){ };
```

But at the end of the day, it is a bad design to expose object instance before it is fully constructed.

Comment: I didn't notice I had the same problem in the constructor, but you're right. Moving registration to testObs would solve this, but this makes the calls to add/remove the concern of the implementer of an observer, which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: It appears that there is also a race with its destructor, ha! :-)

Comment: Yes, I was aware of the destructor, but didn't notice the constructor ;)

Comment: once I moved registration and deregistration I dont get any exceptions with "pure virtual method called", are you getting any?

Comment: This solves the problem, but is not what I'm aiming for. The idea was to let Observer handle registration. Otherwise each implementation has to remember to add and remove their observer, something I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Perhaps you could protect the call onEvent by a boolean variable "alive" which is set to true only by the testObs constructor and then set it to false in the destructor.
It is difficult to prove negative, but I think it is at least a bad design to expose your object instance before it is fully constructed. Sorry.

Comment: similarly perhaps you could just check whether onEvent is null or not. Such data should also be declared as volatile: for a boolean variable alive it's easy, but not so sure with onEvent which is a method/function.

Comment: @MatthiasB what about adding an empty implementation of onEvent? if there is such a race, you are not really missing anything, are you?

Comment: In the end I implemented it by moving registration to the `testObs` subclasses. It is not ideal, but I think you have good points about not exposing a partially constructed object instance.